# issue with uploading and retriving images to mongoDB using express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, express, mongoose

I am building a beginner fullstack project where I am making a webstore. On here I have an admin route where I can upload new products to my mongoDB database so they get displayed on the store. Like any good webstore, I need images to show off my product, but I am having a hard time writing the code for that feature. I know there is something called GridFS, however my images will never exceed 16 MB so I dont want to overcomplicate my solution.

**See the comments below the arrow in my code for the specific problem I am having**

Schema for my products:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  productName: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  image: {data: Buffer, contentType: String},
  price: {type: Number, required: true}
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", UserSchema);
```

Add new product route:

```
const router = require("express").Router();                       //
const Product = require("../models/Product");                     //
                                                                  //
router.post("/add", async (req, res) => {                    //   //   //
  const newProduct = new Product({                             // / //
    productName: req.body.productName,                           //
    image: {                   // this is where I have no idea what I am doing
      data: req.body.image,    // req.body.image is just the filename, do I need the entire path?
      contentType: 'image/png' // not all images are png, how do I update this depending on image type?
    },
    price: req.body.price
  });
  try {
    const savedProduct = await newProduct.save();
    res.redirect("../products");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("an error occured when adding product");
    res.redirect(400, "../products");
  }
});
```

Display products page:

```
<% products.forEach(product => { %>
  <article>
    <h2><%= product.productName %></h2>
    <div class="price"><%= product.price %></div>
    <img src="<%= product.image %>" alt="">
  </article>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a middleware package like `express-fileupload` to handle file uploads. Here is the documentation for the package [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload).

Assuming the name of the input for the image is `image`, you can access the image's information from `req.files.image`. This object contains the file represented in a buffer and its mimetype. Now you can store these two information in the database like this:

```js
router.post("/add", async (req, res) => {
  const img = req.files.image;
  
  const newProduct = new Product({
    productName: req.body.productName,
    image: {
      data: img.data,  // buffer
      contentType: img.mimetype
    },
    price: req.body.price
  });

  try {
    const savedProduct = await newProduct.save();
    res.redirect("../products");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("an error occured when adding product");
    res.redirect(400, "../products");
  }
});
```

When you want to display this image on the html page, you have to convert the buffer to a base64 representation. You can simply use `.toString("base64")` on the buffer data retrieved from the database. The value of `src` should be in this format `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>` [referance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#syntax):

```js
<% products.forEach(product => { %>
  <article>
    <h2><%= product.productName %></h2>
    <div class="price"><%= product.price %></div>
    <img src="data:<%= product.image.contentType%>;base64,<%= product.image.data.toString('base64')%>" alt="">
  </article>
<% }) %>
```

I haven't tried this but if the code in the ejs file throw an error, try storing the image in base64 encoding in the database, then use the `product.image.data` directly in the ejs file